# Could someone please improve my code for me? (I'm a rookie)

Tags: python

Just want a professionals view on this, thanks in advance if you edit this.
*(if you do)* I'd like this code to be focused on the same topic *(being a dungeon game.)* Thanks for even taking the time to look at this!

```
import time 
    import random

    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    print("Text dungeon explorer!")
    print("COMMANDS:")
    print("inventory -- acceses your current inventory")
    print("hold 'item' -- hold selected item")
    print("attack -- attacks if enemy is approched")
    print("eat -- eats current item held")
    print("use -- uses item held")
    print("open -- opens any available chests in said room")
    print("pickup -- picks up any current items in said room")
    print("drop -- drops held item")
    print("throw -- throws held item")
    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")

    time.sleep(3)

    print ("It's a dark in the dungeon, no food, no wepons. You don't even know where you are... There is an object on the floor, all you can make out of it is that it looks quite like a stick.")

    time.sleep(11)

    ch1 = str(input("Do you take it? [y/n]: "))

    if ch1 in ['y', 'Y', 'Yes', 'YES', 'yes']:
        print("You have taken the stick! A very odd feel to it.")
        time.sleep(2)
        backpack_stick = 1

    else:
          print ("You did not take the stick.")
          backpack_stick = 0

    print ("As you proceed further into the cave, you see a wooden door.")
    time.sleep(6)
    ch2 = str(input("Do you open the door? [y/n]"))

    enmysleep_rat = int(random.randomint(1, 10))
    enmychn_rat = int(random.randomint(1, 10))
    chstchnc = int(random.randomint(1, 10))
    if enmychn_rat == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4:
      enmychance_rat = True
      if enmychance_rat is True:
         print("Oh no! A musipial rat! You take a closer look if it is sleeping.")

    time.sleep(3)
             if enmychance_rat is True and
        enmysleep_rat = 1 or 2:

             print("The rat is sleeping! I could take the availible loot without fighting!")
    elif enmysleep_rat = 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10:
             print("The rat is not sleeping! Prepare for battle!")
```

Comment: Is there a specific issue with the code you're having trouble with? If there is something specific you can't figure out, you can ask that using a short code example that reproduces the issue. As currently asked, this is too broad

Comment: try code review if there are no specific problems with it

Comment: some recomendations: a) you do not have to convert `input` to string; it already is and b) `backpack_stick = 0` this method of keeping track of items is very inefficient as it creates too many variables. Use a dict instead `backpack = {'stick': 0}`. c) `randomint` returns an integer. again no conversion necessary. d) `if enmychn_rat == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4:` does not do what you think it does

Comment: Fix indentation, since it's a critical think in python that may lead to unnoticed but catastrophic behavior.

Comment: Thanks! I really didn't think anyone would reply because I know that forums don't take kindly to this kind of stuff.

Comment: I would highly recommend using memorable names for all variables.  I have no idea what chstchnc and ch1 are suppose to mean, just a heads up.  Additionally, most programmer use input.lower().startsWith("y") to check for yes answers.  The .lower function will make it so you're only checking what you really need to, regardless of capitalization.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

```
if ch1 in ['y', 'Y', 'Yes', 'YES', 'yes']:
```

1. Could be replaced with the following (note: my suggestion will fail if you wee to write something like 'nay' to say no because it has a 'y' in it). Edit: someone else suggested using  input.lower().startsWith("y") which is better than what I've suggested and wouldn't fail if you typed 'nay'

```
if 'y' in ch1.lower():
```

2. Also,

```
if enmychn_rat == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4:
```

Could be replaced with

```
if enmychn_rat in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
```

I'm pretty sure your original line is not going to do what you intend. It evaluates to

```
if enmychn_rat == 1 or True or True or True:
```

Which is always True.

```
if enmychance_rat is True
```

Can be changed to simply

```
if enmychance_rat
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, you don't test your ch2 variable for door. Try to make some definitions.
Make some all-around cases, like probably in future you will have more and more "creatures" like the rat.
For a "real" game feeling, try to make random events, like, if you have a "action", like a door opening, do you take it etc, you can specify events for them.

Make more creatures, like this.

import random

```
def creature():
    creatures = ["rat","pig","parrot","monster"]
    life = random.randint(1,10)
    is_asleep_var = random.randint(1,6)
    if is_asleep_var == 1:
        is_asleep = "sleeping"
    else:
        is_asleep = "awake"
    print ("Oh a " + creatures[random.randint(0,len(creatures)-1)]+" with "+str(life)+" life, who is " + str(is_asleep))

while(1):

    creature()
    raw_input()
```

make more and more events, creatures. Events could trigger creatures. You should investigate objects. Make a charachter object, a monster object, add life to them, attack points etc, make levels.